# javascript strange error, console is not giving any errors..

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

The following is my code, i intend to use it as a bookmarklet.

```
javascript: (function () {   
    var jsCode = document.createElement('script');   
    jsCode.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');                    
    document.body.appendChild(jsCode);
    console.log("Everything is fine upto here!");
    data = [["#txtApplcntName","test"],["#txtApplcntAdd","test"]];
    console.log(data);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var current = obj[i];
      console.log(current);
        $(current[0]).val(current[1]);
    };

 })();
```

Problems start when the actions in the for loop never take place. It gets even weirder when i can successfully log the variable obj and it logs, but when i do obj.length a null is encountered?

I am experimenting on Google chrome

Comment: `data` is not JSON plus you didn't declare it.

Comment: Can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: You want to use JSON but I'm not sure you really know what JSON is. `$.parseJSON()` expects, well, JSON. You feed it with an array, not with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = '[["#txtApplcntName","test"],["#txtApplcntAdd","test"]]';
```

Method `JSON.parse(str, reviver)` reads a **string**.
What you're trying to do is treat an ordinary array as JSON.

Comment: My god.. To think i missed such a thing.. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

`var obj = $.parseJSON(data)`

obj get a null ."data" can't convert to json object.